# How to write a python script that does the same thing as this postman request

Tags: python, image, post, python-requests, postman

Need to make a request call to upload an image, this is a form-data with not just image

I have tried several ways to mimic the request in the postman image, mostly are different ways to create a data dictionary and put that in the post request

```py
def uploadimage():

    datain = {
        "file": open('test.png','rb').read(),
        "use": "logoGroup-staging",
        "logoGroup": {"_id": "5d42145db3ef8c0031128763", "name":"sstimagetest2", "longName": "sss",
                           "createdAt": "2019-07-31T22:21:17.680Z", "updatedAt": "2019-07-31T22:21:17.680Z", "__v": 0},
        "imageType": {"_id":"5cfeb4703509f72b616bf7b6","name":"colorhybridnw","__v":0,"createdAt":"2019-06-10T19:50:08.928Z","height":"0","type":"Manual","updatedAt":"2019-06-10T19:50:08.928Z","width":"0"}
    }

    response = requests.post(
        'https://xxxxxxxxxx/api/upload',
        data = datain
    )
```

in all my tries, it can conclude to 3 error categories, wrong python data format(not able to run) , 400 bad request call, 502 bad gateway call
[image]

Comment: What api are you using, cant do much to help you without seeings the required POST format.

Comment: Sorry, first time creating a question, I have just added the image for the post format I want

Comment: You should include headers too. `res = req.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=datain)`

Comment: I also tried with/without headers in postman, it works either way, when I try in python, both with or without header didn't work

Comment: Can you post a link to the docs you are working with?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests

files = {'file': open('test.png','rb').read()}
datain = {'all': 'other', 'data': 'not', 'file': 'upload'}

r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=datain)
```

And [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) with take care of the multi-part form POST.

Comment: I tried to change to that way, the new error is
for (k, v) in files:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)